# Moving Keyboard above control

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to move the on screen keyboard above a control with Windows Phone 7? I'm planning on having action buttons at the bottom of my pages, but I think they will be hidden by the soft keyboard. I'm trying to emulate how WP7 OS does it in the settings section (you can use an unlocked emulator to see what I'm talking about). Settings - system - find my phone. It asks for Windows Live credentials with 2 buttons at the very bottom that are displayed right below the keyboard.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking for a way to do this too.
Unfortunately, there doesn't apper to be a way to do this though.

The next best alternative I've found is to use application bar buttons as these are displayed below the on screen keyboard.  Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: This is the only way I've found of moving the keyboard up as well.